# Visual Studio 2005 and SQL Express 2008

Tags: visual-studio

We are having some issues applying the patch for VS 2005 standard:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e1109aef-1aa2-408d-aa0f-9df094f993bf&displaylang=en

This works fine in profesional edition, but not a machine running standard. We have checked it has all the pre-resequites but no luck at all.

The error is saying the patch cannot be applied because another patch is missing, but again, we have checked and checked and checked.

Now, the KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954961

Says Pro and Team editions, no mention of Standard. Judging by how simple it has been to apply this patch to VS 05 pro, and this KB article, we are starting to come to the conlcusion that it is the version.

Anyone had this issue? Try as we might we cant find any work around

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on Windows 7 RC.  After installing SP1 for SQL 2008 Express did it finally took.